# Always calculate var Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I'm trying to show a variable on a html page that should always recalculating itself.

```
var actualTimeSec = 0; //evolves while the page is loaded
var xTot = 500;        //fixed
var timeTotSec = 60;   //fixed

while(stop === false){
    var x = (actualTimeSec*xTot)/timeTotSec;
    document.querySelector("#xId").innerHTML = x;
}
```

And in my HTML, I have a div showing the x variable.
But when the while loop is working, I can't click on any other button. 
How can I always calculate the x variable (until the user closes the page) but still being able to click on other buttons ?

Comment: You should use `setInterval()` to run code repeatedly, not a `while` loop. JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptable, so the loop can't be interrupted to update any of the variables.

Comment: Of course, but the setInterval() would be every 10ms or something because I want the variable to be accurate. You're maybe right, I should probably use this...

Comment: You can also use `requestAnimationFrame` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'Barmar' said in comments, I should put the content of the loop inside a function and call the function with the `setInterval()` method. (It would call the function every 10ms for example, without breaking the rest of the page)